# Apply Theme File in Delphi2009

Tags: delphi, themes

Is it able to apply a ".theme" file to my app written in Delphi2009? I'm going to custom my app's look and feel, but by default, Delphi2009 has applied the UxTheme.dll and follow the Windows OS theme, what i need is to custom some components' color style, as a result, i've prepare a ".theme" file with the correct color value, but how can i apply it to the app so that it won't affect the default Windows style?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A .theme file contains customisation settings for an entire desktop. It is of no use for your goals. Windows does not perform per application theming. That requires custom drawing from the application, or third party add-ons like Window Blinds.

The easiest way to theme your app is to upgrade to the lates Delphi and use VCL styles, the feature introduced in XE2.

Comment: Sorry that i cannot upgrade my Delphi, and how about ThemeServices? I cannot find a good sample about it...

Comment: Then you'll have to write your own version of VCL styles. The OS won't help you. As I explained, Windows themes all apps the same way. There is no per-app styling from Windows. You have to do that yourself. And VCL styles is Embarcadero doing just that.